# How much does a clone cost?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-clone-wars, clones, attack-of-the-clones

The clone troopers that formed the basis of the Republic's new army were paid for by a combination of Count Dooku's wealth — which was apparently staggering — and [other funds](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/65708/40294).

[image]

**What was the price per clone?**

Specifically, I would like to have an *average price based on the total order*, with the type of currency indicated.  Also, feel free to exclude the fee paid to Jango Fett for allowing his genetic profile to be used by the Kaminoans.  (If you are factoring it in, please indicate this.)

Canon information is preferred but, in the absence of this, non-canon sources and reasonable speculation are welcome.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be much consensus on a [total number](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Grand_Army_of_the_Republic#Numbers), though that doesn't preclude discovering the average price necessarily.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The short story "[Republic Commando: Odds](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Odds)" sets a lower bound for us. Lama Su contacts Palpatine and insists that if he wants any more clones, he'll need to drop an *initial* payment of a billion credits. By definitions then, the GAR (including ships, training and materiel) must have cost at least *2* billion, but presumably much much more.

> But they watched, transfixed, as the shimmering blue image of Lama Su
>   sprang to life from the datapad emitter.
>
> “If you require more clones beyond the current order, then you must
>   authorize us to begin further production immediately. An initial
>   payment of one billion credits….”
>
> There was a crackling pause: Palpatine’s response wasn’t recorded, but
>   it was clear he had interrupted. Lama Su’s head bobbed in annoyance.

The would place the minimum cost per clone at **at least 666 credits.**

Comment: I would think that there is a discount on bulk orders, so a single clone would cost far more than each clone in an order of 100 clones.

Comment: @WadCheber - LIke a "Buy one army, get one army free" kind of a deal?

Comment: Anyone else get a chill after reading each costs 666 credits? Spooky.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are there any estimates about how much 1 credit would be in present day, real life currencies?

Comment: @InTheAbsenceOfFear - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/181869/20774

Comment: Why buy one clone army, when you can buy two for twice the price?

Answer (score -1):

It would have to be much more than 2 billion credits. In "Republic Commando: True Colors", chapter 5, Besany Wennen discovered that 1 warship alone would cost several billion credits, and the Republic had an entire fleet. Therefore, it would have to be over a Trillion credits, at the very least.

Comment: Do you have the quote for this you can [edit] in to support your argument? Also the question is asking the price of an **individual** clone not the total price, do you have an answer for that you can address?

Answer (score -4):

I would like many things if you buy in bulk it will probably be cheaper. also if you simply have them cloned and then raise them yourself it would probably also be cheaper. but if you want to simply have a one off clone without leaving it there for years on end for training then it would probably cost you between 1400-2000 credits for small orders of clones.

Comment: What is this information based on? A good answer should include both assertions and evidence to back those assertions up, rather than just assertions on their own. Also note that the question was asking for the average price of an individual clone, rather than a bulk order price.