# How much did the first batch of 20,000 clones cost the republic?

Tags: star-wars, clones

Without including weapons (1,000 credits per blaster), armour (though I'd love to know how much one set of Phase I armour costs), and DNA (I bet it cost the republic extra to have a famous warrior like Jango provide the genes), what did 20,000 clones cost the Republic?

A good answer will include an estimate of what training may have cost, however, please note that training would take place over roughly five years.  Clones are battle ready at age ten, but are technically ten years old after five years due to their doubled growth rate.
How much would 20,000 cost?

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer Valorum gave from this question as a guide on [how much an individual clone would cost](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/96588/how-much-does-a-clone-cost?rq=1), 20,000 clones would cost **13,320,000 credits** (assuming one clone costs 666 credits, therefore 20,000 * 666 = 13,320,000.)