# What is one Galactic Credit worth?

Tags: star-wars, money

I am doing a project for school and was wondering what Star Wars credits are worth. I've found out [what it would cost to fill up the Millennium Falcon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/180210/how-much-does-it-cost-to-refuel-the-millennium-falcon) but that doesn't help me to estimate what the actual purchasing power of a single credit is.

**What can I buy with a single Galactic Credit that I might recognise?**

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V02924KCrZQ

Comment: @Ummdustry It's not that much! I expected it to be more like 1 credit = 1 bitcoin.

Comment: It's exactly 1/17000th of the price of a Imperial-entaglements-avoiding ticket from Tatooine to Alderaan.

Comment: Unless you are able to find someone willing to trade goods/services for the currency, it is worth exactly 0 US dollars.

Comment: I think that asking what the buying power of one credit is would be more useful (e.g. how many credits does it take to buy a decent meal), since that is something you can compare to USD.

Comment: If you count the prequels and even the new stuff, Star Wars takes place over half a century if not more. How can anyone answer that question? I don't know anything about dollars, but I know that a cup of coffee in Amsterdam or Paris is like 8 Euros and in Eastern Germany perhaps 2 or less. Please be aware that such things are not constant in time and place

Comment: Hmm... Looks like the Big Mac Index doesn't include Galactic Credits...

Answer (score 31):

**In real-world terms, the Galactic Credit seems to be roughly analogous to a US dollar although certain items are going to be massively cheaper as a result of droid labour or massively more expensive depending on the relative purchasing power of your credit, your distance from the Empire/Republic and the rarity of the item you're purchasing.**

It's also worth distinguishing between Republic Credits (which not everyone accepts), Imperial Credits (which seem broadly acceptable everywhere) and New Republic Credits (which are pretty useless).

---

- According to [Rebel in the Ranks](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Servants_of_the_Empire:_Rebel_in_the_Ranks), a single credit will buy you a raffle ticket.

  > *“Hi,” one of them said breathlessly. “We’re selling raffle tickets to
  >   raise funds for our Junior Academy camping trip in the Westhills.
  >   Would you like to buy one? It’s for a good cause and **a ticket is only
  >   one credit.”***
- Six credits will buy you a meal on Five Points Station

  > *One hundred credits. She had to make it last. But first: food. Jyn
  >   slipped out of the reeking public bathroom stall and headed deeper
  >   into the station. She clung to the outer perimeter of the main floor,
  >   where the shops were smaller but cheaper. A bodega built between two
  >   towers of residential cubes looked local enough not to extort her too
  >   badly. **She bought a can of nutritive milk that was dusty on top and a
  >   tube of dehydrated vegetable protein straws.** Not the tastiest but
  >   definitely the healthiest, most filling option; this would last her
  >   the whole day if she was careful. Food was important. Hunger would
  >   make her careless, an easy target. Food and sleep were vital to
  >   survival. Ninety-four credits left.*
  >
  > <sub><sup>[Rebel Rising](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rebel_Rising)</sup></sub>
- A room for the night will cost you 13 credits.

  > *Maybe they just want to rob me, she thought. But she couldn’t be sure.
  >   An inn had rooms for rent, and Jyn passed over more of her meager supply of credits.
  >
  >   Sixty-seven left.*
  >
  > <sub><sup>[Rebel Rising](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rebel_Rising)</sup></sub>
- A can of bug spray will set you back four credits (in a seller's market)

  > “*Nazgorigan’s patented bug repellent. Guaranteed to make the little bugs buzz off. How many would you like?”
  >
  >   “Sorry?” Lina asked.
  >
  >   “How many would you like to buy? You won’t get far on Thune without one can or seven. Unless you like scratching yourself until you’re raw, yes?”
  >
  >   “Okay, we’ll take one,” Milo said, pulling a credit chip from his pocket. “How much?”
  >
  >   **“Four credits each,” the alien replied.
  >
  >   “Four credits? That’s a bit expensive!” Milo said**.*
  >
  > <sub><sup>[Adventures in Wild Space](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Adventures_in_Wild_Space)</sup></sub>
- Two alcoholic drinks in the Alcazar will cost you ten credits.

  > “*Two drinks. I’ll have a…” He turns to the Twi’lek. “You first, friend. What are you having?”
  >
  >   “An…ale?”
  >
  >   The Twi’lek looks nervous.
  >
  >   Sinjir makes a face. “He’ll have an ale. I need something stronger. You got ahh, let’s see. Jogan fruit brandy?”
  >
  >   “Kind of a fancy place you think this is?” the bartender rumbles. “I got ale. More ale. Other ale. Different ale. Grog. And starfire ’skee.”
  >
  >   “I’ll take that last decoction, then. A jorum of ’skee for me.”
  >
  >   **The bartender grumbles. Begins pouring a glass of something brown and muddy before sliding a bottle of foaming ale to the Twi’lek. “That’ll be ten credits.”***
  >
  > <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Aftermath](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Aftermath)</sup></sub>

Comment: Republic credits ain't good here..

Comment: They'll do just fine */waves hand*

Comment: I'll upvote this post for ten thousand credits, all in advance.

Comment: Fun Fact: At Star Wars: Galaxy's Edge, a credit is exactly one US dollar. A glass of Blue Milk cost me 8 credits!