# Did Sidious have both Maul and Dooku as apprentices at one time?

Tags: star-wars, sith, darth-sidious, darth-tyranus, darth-maul

We know that Dooku paid the Pyke syndicate to kill Sifo-Dyas sometime during the chancellorship of Finis Valorum. We know that because Valorum personally sent Sifo-Dyas to negotiate with the Pykes.

We also know that Darth Maul was bisected and went missing in last days of Valorum's rule, during the Naboo crisis.

Since Jedi do not kill fellow Jedi, this raises the question: did Dooku fall to the Dark Side and become the apprentice of Sidious before Maul was bisected?

P.S. In [S06E10](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Lost_One) of *Clone Wars* it is revealed that Dooku used his Sith name (Tyranus) to introduce himself to the Pyke syndicate when he contracted for the murder of Syfo-Dias. Since an apprentice usually gets his name from his master when he joins the Sith, this leaves even less chance that Dooku was not a Sith at that time.

To further complicate the matter, in Legends Sidious killed his master Plagueis on the night when he become chancellor, thus implying we had four Sith (instead of two) roaming about at some point in time.

Comment: It was known at the time that Dooku fell to the Dark Side, but it was not clear was he affiliated with the Sith or not.

Comment: @TimSparrow Why would he kill Sifo-Dyas if he did not know Sith Grand Plan with Clone Army ?

Comment: he might have other issues with him, probably personal. Being on the Dark Side may open these opportunities. Or he might have been manipulated by Sidious, and offered to join him later. 

I think someone who read more books on the topic will have the answer.

Comment: Technically this is not possible because of the Rule of Two. Only one of them would be considered the "true" apprentice even if both were under training by Sidious at the same time. Of course, Sidious had multiple "apprentices" at varying points in time in Legends.

Comment: In the now legends novel "Darth Plagueis", Sidious had a young Maul as an apprentice while he was still Plagueis' apprentice himself. It's not like the bad guys follow the rules all the time...even their own.

Comment: @tilley31 Yes, but that novel never mentions Dooku being apprentice at the same time. And that would be a huge thing, considering that Dooku was even more powerful then Maul.

Comment: @rs.29 yes, the same novel actually depicts the "preliminary" conversations between Dooku and Palpatine and how he planned to turn him as soon as he got rid of Plagueis. Maul was already his apprentice at the time. It think it was the plan, but then Maul got "high grounded" by Obi-Wan and he had to settle with Dooku.

Comment: @TimSparrow Sifo-Dyas could have stolen his girlfriend :) , but this does not explain why man called Tyranus (his Sith name !) contacted the Pykes to order the murder. In S06E10 of Clone Wars, everything points out that Dooku killed Dyas to take over his project of Clone Army.

Comment: @tilley31 As I recall, Palpatine almost revealed himself to Dooku when he become Chancellor in that novel, but he restrained himself at that moment. Dooku has left Jedi Order but they both mention Sifo-Dias as being alive at the time.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes

In *Tales of the Jedi* Episode 4: The Sith Lord, Dooku meets with Sidious during the events of *The Phantom Menace*, after Darth Maul is believed dead. He and Sidious make reference to orders that Sidious has been giving and Dooku has been following ("Sifo-Dyas, Kamino, the clones"). While it's not clear if Dooku was yet Sidious's official Sith apprentice, by the end he refers to Sidious as "Master".

Answer (score 1):

In Legends, Dooku did not leave the Jedi Order until after Qui-Gon's death, and while Sidious was meeting with Dooku, and presumably manipulating him, Sidious did not give Dooku the name Darth Tyranus until after Qui-Gon had gone.

From Star Wars wikia - [Leaving the Order](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dooku/Legends#Leaving_the_Order)

Comment: This directly contradicts canon information that Dooku killed Sifo-Dyas while Valorum was still chancellor.

Comment: That's probably because Legends and Canon contradict each other a lot

Answer (score 0):

We don’t know when Darth Plagueis dies in canon so that’s not a problem. But Dave Filoni said in an interview that he ran into this problem when writing the episodes about Sifo Dyas. So yes Sidious had two apprentices at the same time. As for the rule of two I think Sidious never intended to have Dooku be his apprentice permanently unlike Maul.

Comment: Could you [edit] in a link to the interview and the quote from Dave Filoni to back this answer up? At the moment it answers the question but requires the reader to go find the evidence themselves. It could be a good answer if you edited it in though.

Comment: In one of the first scenes of episode III, Sidious has a long speech in which he explains that he believes in human supremacy and that he never intended for Maul to be a long-term apprentice, because Maul was "just an animal". (This scene is cut in some of the releases - I've seen it when I first saw episode III in a theater, and it can be found in DVDs, but whenever episode III is broadcasted on TV that scene appears to be left out)

Answer (score -6):

No, due to the rule of two, Sidious would be unable to take 2 apprentices at one time. The rule of two stated only two Sith could be at the top of the Empire (one Sith lord and his apprentice = Sidious and Maul). Dooku left Sidious's apprenticeship before he took on Maul.

Comment: Do you have any evidence of such?

Comment: Gosh cause baddies have never broken rules :)

Comment: Sith following rules? Yeah, right.

Comment: Only a Sith deals in absolutes.